# How to use an imported 3rd party library in Storybook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook, highlight.js

I have the following React component which renders a block of code using `react-highlight.js`. The component is:

```
import React from 'react';
import './CodeBlock.scss';
import Highlight from 'react-highlight.js';

const CodeBlock = (props) => {
    const { language, title, code } = props;
    return (
        <>
            <Highlight className={language}>
                <div children={code} />
            </Highlight>
            <p className='code-block-title'>{title}</p>
        </>
    )
}

export default CodeBlock;
```

To use it:

```
<CodeBlock language='javascript'
    title='demo script'
    code={`let A = new Array(3);
A.forEach((_, index) => {
    A[index] = 1;
});
console.log(A);
// [undefined, undefined, undefined]
`}
/>
```

which renders like this:

[image]

Now I'd like to write a Storybook for it. I have the following Storybook code:

```
import React from 'react';

import CodeBlock from './CodeBlock';

export default {
    title: 'Components/CodeBlock',
    component: CodeBlock,
    argTypes: {
        language: {
            name: 'language',
            type: { name: 'string', required: false },
            defaultValue: null,
            description: 'programming language',
            control: { type: 'text' }
        }
    }
};

const Template = (args) => <CodeBlock {...args} />

export const ReactDemo = Template.bind({});
ReactDemo.args = {
    language: 'react',
    title: 'Demo React Code Block',
    code: `let A = new Array(3);
A.forEach((_, index) => {
    A[index] = 1;
});
console.log(A);
// [undefined, undefined, undefined]`
};
```

The problem is, Storybook shows the code without syntax highlight. I inspected the Storybook code, and found that the classes were there, but they were all empty with no styling. I assume that `react-highlight.js` wasn't successfully imported in Storybook, how can I fix it?